Convert pandas Dataframe to 3D numpy matrix
I have a pandas.DataFrame as given below you can read it as pd.DataFrame(data_dict):
data_dict = 
{'Elevation': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1},
 'Azimuth': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 4},
 'median': {0: 255,
  1: 255,
  2: 255,
  3: 255,
  4: 255,
  5: 256,
  6: 256,
  7: 256,
  8: 256,
  9: 256},
 'count': {0: 255,
  1: 255,
  2: 255,
  3: 255,
  4: 255,
  5: 250,
  6: 250,
  7: 250,
  8: 250,
  9: 250},
 'to_drop': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 0,
  6: 0,
  7: 0,
  8: 0,
  9: 0}}

I want to convert it to a 3D matrix in numpy. The shape of the 3D matrix would be [Azimuth.nunique(), Elevation.nunique(), 3(Median,count,to_drop)] i.e, [5,2,3].
I have tried data.groupby(['Elevation','Azimuth']).apply(lambda x: x.values).reset_index().values that results in 10,3 array. How to get 5,2,3 array?

First pivoting by DataFrame.pivot with DataFrame.stack and then convert MultiIndex DataFrame to 3d array - first with DataFrame.to_xarray:
out = (df.pivot(index='Elevation', columns='Azimuth').stack(level=0, future_stack=True)
         .to_xarray().to_array())
print (out)
<xarray.DataArray (variable: 5, Elevation: 2, level_1: 3)>
array([[[255, 255,   1],
        [250, 256,   0]],

       [[255, 255,   1],
        [250, 256,   0]],

       [[255, 255,   1],
        [250, 256,   0]],

       [[255, 255,   1],
        [250, 256,   0]],

       [[255, 255,   1],
        [250, 256,   0]]], dtype=int64)
Coordinates:
  * Elevation  (Elevation) int64 0 1
  * level_1    (level_1) object 'count' 'median' 'to_drop'
  * variable   (variable) int32 0 1 2 3 4


print (out.shape)
(5, 2, 3)

Another idea is use numpy.reshape and numpy.transpose:
df1 = df.pivot(index='Elevation', columns='Azimuth').stack(level=0, future_stack=True)

out = df1.to_numpy().reshape(*df1.index.levshape,-1).transpose(2, 0, 1)
print (out)
[[[255 255   1]
  [250 256   0]]

 [[255 255   1]
  [250 256   0]]

 [[255 255   1]
  [250 256   0]]

 [[255 255   1]
  [250 256   0]]

 [[255 255   1]
  [250 256   0]]]

